# .Net Forms PropertyGrid ignores DisplayNameAttribute when sorting properties on multiple selected objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to make the `.NET Forms` `PropertyGrid` respect the `DisplayNameAttribute` when it sorts properties of multiple selected objects. When a single object is select the `PropertyGrid` sorts based on the `DisplayNameAttribute` but when multiple objects are selected, it uses the actual property name to sort.

The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form myForm1 = new Form();
        myForm1.Width = 820;
        myForm1.Height = 340;

        PropertyGrid grid1 = new PropertyGrid();
        grid1.Left = 0;
        grid1.Top = 0;
        grid1.Width = 400;
        grid1.Height = 300;
        myForm1.Controls.Add(grid1);

        grid1.SelectedObject = new MyObject();

        PropertyGrid grid2 = new PropertyGrid();
        grid2.Left = 400;
        grid2.Top = 0;
        grid2.Width = 400;
        grid2.Height = 300;
        myForm1.Controls.Add(grid2);

        object[] objects = new object[] { new MyObject(), new MyObject() };
        grid2.SelectedObjects = objects;

        Application.Run(myForm1);
    }
}


public class MyObject
{
    [DisplayName("ZZZZ")]
    public int AProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("BBBB")]
    public int BProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

}
```

The previous code makes a `Form` with **two** `PropertyGrids`. The left grid contains a single object in its selection, while the right grid contains two objects in its selection.

[image]

All objects are of the same type. The left **grid sorts** the `properties` based on the `DisplayNameAttribute` while the right sorts based on the actual property name. In both cases the `DisplayNameAttribute` is presented as the properties name in the grid:

Can I **force** the `PropertyGrid` to always use the `DisplayNameAttribute` when **sorting**?

Comment: Wow Microsoft..... what's the point of displaying an alphabetical sort... if you aren't sorting on the displayed name?

There should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have found an answer to my problem. Yes it is possible to "`force`",or perhaps more correctly "`trick`", the `PropertyGrid` into always respecting the `DisplayName` when sorting. The heart of the issue was in the fact the the 'PropertyGrid' uses the actual property name when sorting the properties of multiple selected object. So in order to get the desired behavior, we have to make the grid believe that the `DisplayName` is the actual property name. The `PropertyGrid` uses `PropertyDescriptors` to discover the various attributes of an objects properties. We simply need a custom `PropertyDescriptor` that will present the `DisplayName` as the actual property name. Behold the following code:

```
public class DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private PropertyDescriptor _descriptor;
    public DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor descriptor)
        : base(descriptor)
    {
        this._descriptor = descriptor;
    }

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayName) ? base.Name : DisplayName;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
    {
        return _descriptor.CanResetValue(component);
    }

    public override Type ComponentType
    {
        get
        {
            return _descriptor.ComponentType;
        }
    }

    public override object GetValue(object component)
    {
        return _descriptor.GetValue(component);
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return _descriptor.IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public override Type PropertyType
    {
        get
        {
            return _descriptor.PropertyType;
        }
    }

    public override void ResetValue(object component)
    {
        _descriptor.ResetValue(component);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
    {
        _descriptor.SetValue(component, value);
    }

    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
    {
        return _descriptor.ShouldSerializeValue(component);
    }
}
```

The previous class is used to wrap an existing `PropertyDescriptor` and override the behavior of the 'Name' property.  The `Name` property will now return the `DisplayName` (if not null or empty) or the actual properties name. All other functionality is delegated to the wrapped `PropertyDescriptor`.

So now we have a way to alter the presented property name, we just need to have the `PropertyGrid` utilize the new `PropertyDescriptor`. To do so we need a customized `TypeDescriptor`.  Once again, behold the following code:

```
public class DisplayNameEnforcingConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection original = base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
        List<DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor> descriptorList = new List<DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in original)
            descriptorList.Add(new DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor(descriptor));
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(descriptorList.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This class inherits from `ExpandableObjectConverter` to utilize its existing behavior and minimize our implementation. We only need to override the `GetProperties` method. This methods asks the base type to get the relevant `PropertyDescriptorCollection` then wraps all the elements of this collection in our `DisplayNameEnforcingDescriptor`. A new `collection` is returned contaning our wrapped elements.

Now if we attribute the `MyObject` class with the `DisplayNameEnforcingConverter`, sorting will always happen based on a properties `DisplayName`

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DisplayNameEnforcingConverter))]
public class MyObject
{
    [DisplayName("ZZZZ")]
    public int AProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("BBBB")]
    public int BProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [PropertyGrid.PropertySortOrder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.propertysort.aspx) states:

> To do custom sorting, implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) on the component
>   to return the properties in the desired order.

I modified your class to implement the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and while the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` methods were getting called and were returning the properties in order by the attribute `DisplayName`, `PropertyGrid.SelectObjects` still insists on sorting by actual property name:

```
public class MyObject : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    [DisplayName("ZZZZ")]
    public int AProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DisplayName("BBBB")]
    public int BProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        // Creates a new collection and assign it the properties for button1.
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)
                          .OfType<PropertyDescriptor>();
        var result = properties.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(result.ToArray());
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true)
                          .OfType<PropertyDescriptor>();
        var result = properties.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(result.ToArray());
    }

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(this, true);
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(this, true);
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(this, true);
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(this, true);
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(this, editorBaseType, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, attributes, true);
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(this, true);
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Since that doesn't work, it seems that the answer to your question is, No, you can't force the `PropertyGrid` to sort on `DisplayNameAttribute` when selecting multiple objects.